# Auto scale element in LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have a simple fragmet and I want it to look like this image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0WGO.png).

My fragment code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:context=".SignFragment">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/wrapper_padding">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/example" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/infoMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/info_message_example"
            android:textColor="@color/colorInfoMessage"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But my fragmet looks like this image: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOlDN.png).
On the Landscape variation text is hiden.

I tried adding some attribute on `<LinearLayout/>` or other elements.
And when I added android:layout_weight="1" on first ConstraintLayout I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKMLE.png).

Landscape variation is correct, but portrait orientation is broken.

How can I chage my xml-file to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

To create separate fragment designs for portrait and landscape mode, create two different `XML` files, one for design in portrait mode and other for landscape mode. Put in `layout-port` and `layout-land` folder inside `res folder`.

Example:

```
res/layout-port [Portrait Mode; default]
main.xml
res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main1.xml
```

Reference Documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html